# What is the "prep work" for android / ios development in monero .11.1.0 release?

Tags: android-wallet, ios-wallet

https://getmonero.org/2017/10/27/monero-0.11.1.0-released.html

There is "prep work" on the release for android and ios. What is this prep work? Is core making their own android wallet or does this means it will make it easier to support mobile wallets?

Comment: Preparation work means Monero Core Team is going to prepare the full support for Android and iOS platform.